# java 拡張for文のmap型変数のkeyを取得したい

Tags: java

javaについて。
拡張for文の変数(この変数とは例を挙げると`for(int num : array)`の`num`になります)が`Map<String, String>`型の場合、拡張for文の処理の中でkeyを取得するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

```
for (Map<String, String> map : rankingList) {　　//rankingListはList<Map<String, String>型
          //keyを取得して処理をしたい      
 }
```

自分で調べても解決できなかったので、教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map<String, String>`中のkeyをすべて取得するのであれば、`Map<String, String>.keySet()`(keyの`Set`を取得するメソッド)でよいと思います。

```
// 例
for (Map<String, String> map : rankingList) {
    for (String k : map.keySet()) {
        // k に対する処理
    }
}
```

`map`の値も参照するのであれば、`Map<String, String>.entrySet()`のほうが便利と思います。

```
// 例
for (Map<String, String> map : rankingList) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        // 処理
    }
}
```